# Do pthread_mutex_unlock immediate context switch?

Tags: linux, multithreading, real-time

The `pthread_mutex_unlock` is called on mutex, and another thread with higher real-time priority is waiting for that mutex. Will be the context switch done during such system call, or the thread will be preempted only after quantum end?
If immediate context switch is not guaranteed in such case, is it good idea to call `sched_yield` immediately after each `pthread_mutex_unlock`?

Answer (score 2):

> The pthread_mutex_unlock is called on mutex, and another thread with higher real-time priority is waiting for that mutex. Will be the context switch done during such system call, or the thread will be preempted only after quantum end?

Typically, if there isn't another core available to run the higher-priority thread, the unlocking thread will be pre-empted.

> If immediate context switch is not guaranteed in such case, is it good idea to call sched_yield immediately after each pthread_mutex_unlock?

It is not guaranteed, nor could it be. The other thread might not be ready-to-run.

It's a terrible idea to call sched_yield immediately after the pthread_mutex_unlock. Even low priority threads will harm the performance of high priority threads through things like cache contention, so making your low priority threads inefficient with needless extra context switches will harm the high priority threads.

Don't fix it if it isn't broken. The implementation understands priorities and will do its best.

Comment: So when the unlocking thread will be preempted - before return from `pthread_mutex_unlock` or later (by timer IRQ), in case of only one ready-to-run thread with higher realtime priority, which was waiting for that mutex, and single core CPU?

Comment: @Marik Your implementation will do the best it can. You're not using a real time OS, so it doesn't make hard guarantees about things like this.